# Laravel Sanctum (Former airlock) - How do I issue tokens for other models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I am trying laravel sanctum for the first time.

I want to issue tokens for an Eloquent Model called Campaign.

This is my Campaign.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Campaign extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['percentage'])->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I put the `HasApiTokens` trait on it.

With this, I can issue a token to any campaign like that:

```
$campaign->createToken('my-token-name');
```

So far, so good. It works and is correctly stored at the database.

The problem begins when I try to use the token to make any request protected with sanctum's middleware. This is the error that shows when I do it:

```
Call to undefined method App\\Campaign::getAuthIdentifier()
```

Well, I guess this `getAuthIdentifier()` comes from `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` class, which is commonly imported on the User model as `Authenticatable`;

I tried to create this method on my Campaign model and give it a try, that's what I've done:

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return 'id';
}
```

When I tried to post again, it seems to work. But I think it's not correct because it's kind weird. And it gets even worse when I call `auth()->user()` and I am able to access the Campaign object. I know that this is a consequence of what I have done here.

Can this package issue tokens based on something that is not actually an User?

If you know how to do it correctly, I would appreciate an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Campaign extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use HasApiTokens,Authenticatable;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function users()
    {

       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['percentage'])->withTimestamps();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ameer, thank you! I think its a good solution and I have already tried it. It works almost the same way of what I had implemented. I still need to call auth()->user() to get the logged in "campaign". Do you now if there is another way to get logged in model? the auth()->user() approach is a little bit confusing.

Comment: Are you using it for Web or API

Comment: API only. This entity will not be able to login through web. It’s just for some api routes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your comment, if you like to get campaign send token in the header in the request and then search in the token table to find the related campaign